# NodeJs socket.io get all clients on room

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

with `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room]` on this below function i can get all socket id of special room, now i'm trying to push socket id as room clients, but unfortunately i get `undefined` on `socketIds[i]` when i try to use that on `clients.push(chatClients[socketIds[i]]);`

for example:

```
socketIds:{"sockets":{"yJJj6ysKEPp0UhOdAAAA":true,"9dDHXedsMRrjJNhrAAAB":true},"length":2}
```

how can i get all `sockets` from `socketIds` with using `length` ?

```
function getClientsInRoom(socketId, room) {
    // get array of socket ids in this room
    var socketIds = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
    console.log("socketIds:" + JSON.stringify(socketIds));
    var clients = [];

    if (socketIds && socketIds.length > 0) {
        //socketsCount = socketIds.lenght;

        // push every client to the result array
        for (var i = 0, len = socketIds.length; i < len; i++) {

            // check if the socket is not the requesting
            // socket
            if (socketIds[i] != socketId) {
                clients.push(chatClients[socketIds[i]]);
            }
        }
    }

    return clients;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved by this code

```
function getClientsInRoom(socketId, room) {
    // get array of socket ids in this room
    var socketIds = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
    var clients = [];

    if (socketIds && socketIds.length > 0) {
        //socketsCount = socketIds.lenght;

        // push every client to the result array
        for (var i = 0, len = socketIds.length; i < len; i++) {
            // check if the socket is not the requesting
            // socket
            if (socketIds.sockets[i] != socketId) {
                clients.push(chatClients[Object.keys(socketIds.sockets)[i]]);
            }
        }
    }

    return clients;
}
```